# Is there a feasible way to trigger CSS keyframe animation using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Naturally, we can create a CSS animation using keyframes, and control it from there.

However, ideally, I would like to trigger this animation from a button click - so the button click would be an event...

```
@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Now, on click, I want to trigger this animation; as opposed to from within the CSS animation property.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you have some code for us to work with?

Comment: ^ Please add some code. You can add a class which has the animation rule in it using any javascript/jquery event.

Comment: Simple answer is toggle classes that contain the css needed

Comment: Yes, but what about the transition time for the animation?

Comment: Put the transition time in the class that you're toggling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opqjyd5t/1/)**

if you want your animation to work every time you press the button use this code :

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(".fademe").addClass('animated');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".fademe").removeClass('animated');
    }, 1500);
});
```

where `1500` is the `animation-duration` in this case, `1.5s`

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(".fademe").addClass('animated');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".fademe").removeClass('animated');
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.fademe {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.fademe.animated {
  animation: fade-in 1.5s ease;
}


@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fademe">

</div>

<button>CLICK ME</button>
```

EXPLANATION :

1. on click on the button add class `animated` ( or any other class ) to the element you want to apply the animation to , `.fademe`
2. make a `setTimeout(function()` to delay the `removeClass` for the duration of the animation `1.5s` or `1500ms`
3. write in CSS the declaration of the animation , `@keyframes`, and add it to the element with the class added by the JQ `.fademe.animated`

Comment: There's no need to add timeout. Please check my updated answer. You just need to force the browser to re-render by updating some properties of that element.

Comment: well that's one way to do it.. mine..is another solution. both work. no need to downvote my solution....

plus...the `need to force the browser to re-render` doesn't seem like a good idea if you can do this specific example with another, simple, solutin

Comment: You can also listen for the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) event.

Comment: Ok sorry, downvoted thinking that your answer does not add anything useful, but then realised you mentioned that because adding the class was not triggering animation again in my solution. Upvoted now :) . Your way works, but still it should be avoided for obvious reasons.

Comment: which are those 'obvious' reasons ?

Comment: Ok. First and most obvious one is that your animation will trigger 1.5 seconds after you click the button. And what happens if user clicks that multiple times, thinking the first time clicking did not work?

Comment: it doesn't start `1.5s after you click the button` .the animation starts right in the moment when the user clicks the button. and after the animation is complete. if you click again...the animation starts again.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#move-button").on("click", function(){
  $("#ship").removeClass("moving");
  $("#ship")[0].offsetWidth = $("#ship")[0].offsetWidth;
  $("#ship").addClass("moving");
});//
```

```css
#ship
{
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}

#move-button
{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#ship.moving
{
  animation: moving 2s ease;
}

@keyframes moving
{
  0%{ transform: translate(0px);}
  50%{ transform: translate(20px);}
  100%{ transform: translate(0px);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ship">Ship</div>
<button id="move-button">Push</button>
```

Comment: Oh, I guess, in adding the class, the keyframes will 'kick in' and the animation plays as if we were triggering with a CSS event like hover...neat!

Comment: I will try it out and then mark as answer after some time. Thanks.

Comment: @VisWebsoft Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a toggle method that works just fine for this, hope it helps:

```js
function Fade() {
  document.getElementById("box").classList.toggle("animate");
}
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.animate {
  animation: fademe 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fademe {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Animation Trigger
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <button onclick="Fade()"> Fade above Box</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This should be upvoted more. Excellent modern approach 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the animation happen and always end before allowing the event listener to trigger it again, I would suggest to control the behaviour like this:

```
// Add this to your event listener
if (!element.classList.contains("myClass")) {
    element.className = "myClass";
    setTimeout(function() {
        element.classList.remove("myClass");
    }, 1000); //At least the time the animation lasts
}
```